# Redis INCR resetting

Tags: redis

We're running a Redis 2.8.4 instance on a Ubuntu 14.04 server where we're experiencing problems with a key that's being reset to 0.

It's a key we're only running INCR commands on, but every few months it goes to 0. Last time it was at around 29000, so it's not a very big number.

In our codebase, there's only 1 place where the key name is referenced, so I'm a little confused about what's happening.

The only thing i have to go on is an entry in the log (it's a standalone server, no slaves):

```
[1308] 15 Jul 08:37:20.157 * Background saving terminated with success
[1308] 15 Jul 08:40:52.085 # Connection with slave 127.0.0.1:0 lost.
[1308] 15 Jul 08:40:55.042 # Connection with slave 127.0.0.1:0 lost.
[1308] 15 Jul 08:42:21.034 * 10 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
[1308] 15 Jul 08:42:21.034 * Background saving started by pid 28136
```

Comment: I have a same issue on redis 3.2 on windows server in production

Comment: how did you fix this issue?